# Getopt::Long Pushing multiple values in a hash option

Tags: perl

For Example :

```
use Getopt::Long;
%file ;
GetOptions('file=s%' =>
sub { push(@{$file{$_[1]}}, $_[2]) });

use Data::Dumper ;
print Dumper %file ;


print  @{$file{filename}} ;

my @file_array = @{$file_ref};

print "==\n @file_array == ";
```

I can execute and it working :

```
 perl multipls.pl  --file filename=a.txt  --file  filename=b.txt filename=c.txt
```

I am looking for

```
 perl multipls.pl  --file filename=a.txt  filename=b.txt filename=c.txt
```

How to acheive this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to convince `Getopt::Long` to do exactly what you are asking, but I often use shell quoting to group several items into one string, then split the string into an array:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use Getopt::Long;

my @files;
my $filelist;
GetOptions('file=s' => \$filelist);

if ($filelist) {
    $filelist =~ s/^\s+//; # Remove any leading whitespace
    @files = split /\s+/, $filelist;
}
print Dumper(\@files);
```

Command-line example with output:

```
perl multipls.pl --file "filename=a.txt filename=b.txt"

$VAR1 = [
          'filename=a.txt',
          'filename=b.txt'
        ];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;

my @files;

GetOptions ( "file=s{,}" => \@files );
```

**Side Note:**

The example in the problem doesn't really make sense. If all the filenames are going to be pushed to the 'filename' key, does it make sense to have a hash?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `use warnings;` turned on.  If you did, you'd see that you are not actually declaring anything with this line:

```
%file;
```

You'd want that to be

```
my %file;
```

But as another poster said, you don't want it in a hash anyway.  I'm just pointing out the value of `use warnings;`.